# Shrink window in GTK+ dynamically when content shrinks?

Tags: linux, gtk, vala

I have a window in a Vala application and an image inside it.
This image is changed sometimes by `img.set_from_pixbuf(imgdata);` and so it's size changes as well. It's embedded in a Gtk.Box.

```
box = new Gtk.Box(Orientation.VERTICAL,5);
...
box.pack_end(img,false,false);
```

So if there was a big image before and I replace it with a smaller one, the window remains ridiculously big and I have not found a method to dynamically shrink it to the space required.
I have tried with `window.set_default_size(box.width_request,box.height_request)` but it always returns -1.

So any ideas how to resize the window?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a real problem. I constantly run into this (e.g. an item removed from a `Gtk::ListBox` leaves the window to large).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the automatic resizing of windows only only happens when elements are too large to be drawn. Additionally the set_default_size method only matters when first drawing the window and unless I am wrong is never used again. I would suggest using the resize method to set the window size. ([link](http://references.valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Window.resize.html))

```
window.resize(box.width_request, box.height_request);
```

One thing you need to remember when using resize if you can't resize it smaller than the request_size if you run into that issue use the set_request_size method.

Comment: There are several typos here: the actual method names/signatures (which should be equivalent across bindings) are `get_size_request(out width, out height)` and `set_size_request(width, height)`. Besides, `get_size_request` is only meaningful for dimensions whose request has previously been explicitly set; else they're -1. If no explicit request was made, but the user still wants an appropriate size for the widget, they should use `get_preferred_height/_width/_size` instead. This would then allow resizing the window smaller than the preferred dimensions (which is e.g. useful if it's scrollable)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: In addition, GTK4 removes `Window.resize()`, leaving only `Window.set_default_size()`, which it seems, as mentioned, sometimes only works before the window is shown and thereafter is ignored... weirdly it seems Wayland lets it work at any time while X.org does not, whereas usually the converse is true... Sigh, another feature just lost to time.

Answer (score 5):

I have fought with this issue myself and while the accepted answer is correct, I though I could give a more "complete" answer, with working code.

## Reproducing the problem

The following code (In C++, sorry) reproduces your issue:

```cpp
#include <array>

#include <gtkmm.h>

class ResizableWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    ResizableWindow()
    : m_toggle{"Toggle"}
    , m_currentImageIndex{0}
    {
        m_files[0] = "small.png";
        m_files[1] = "large.png";
    
        // Setup window layout:
        m_layout.attach(*Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(m_files[m_currentImageIndex])), 0, 0, 1, 1);
        m_layout.attach(m_toggle, 0, 1, 1, 1);
        add(m_layout);
        
        // Set up signal handlers:
        m_toggle.signal_clicked().connect([this](){OnToggle();});
    }

private:

    void OnToggle()
    {
        // Switch image file:
        if(m_currentImageIndex == 0)
        {
            m_currentImageIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_currentImageIndex = 0;
        }
        
        // Load new image.
        Gtk::Widget* child = m_layout.get_child_at(0, 0);
        Gtk::Image* currentImage = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Image*>(child);
        
        currentImage->set(m_files[m_currentImageIndex]);
    }

    Gtk::Grid m_layout;
    
    Gtk::Button m_toggle;
    
    std::array<std::string, 2> m_files;
    size_t m_currentImageIndex;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "so.question.q8903140");
    
    ResizableWindow w;
    w.show_all();

    return app->run(w);
}
```

The `Toggle` button changes the underlying images. Both are the same image, but with different sizes. Notice that, As you already mentionned, when toggling for the first time (small --> large), the window resizes appropriately. However, when toggling a second time (large --> small), the image is resized, but not the window, leaving extra space around the image:

[image]

Weird, I know...

### Solution

To solve the issue, one needs to call the `resize` method. So the `Toggle` handler would become:

```cpp
void OnToggle()
{
    if(m_currentImageIndex == 0)
    {
        m_currentImageIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        m_currentImageIndex = 0;
    }
    
    Gtk::Widget* child = m_layout.get_child_at(0, 0);
    Gtk::Image* currentImage = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Image*>(child);
    
    currentImage->set(m_files[m_currentImageIndex]);
    
    // Resize window:
    resize(1, 1);
}
```

Note that `resize` was called with dimensions 1x1 (smallest possible dimensions). Gtkmm will resize the window following geometry constraints automatically from there.